# My code is giving me a segmentation error, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fact(int n); 

int main()
{   
    int n,f;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    f=fact(n);
    printf("factorial of %d is %d",n,f);
    return 0;
}
int fact(int n)    
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return 1;

    }
    else
    {
        return n*fact(n-1);

    }
}
```

I was trying to make a basic program on factorial using C and recursive functions, but for some reason, it won't run. On compilation I am getting a Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV).

Comment: Usually, segmentation error gives when you are trying to access a memory location which you are not allowed to. http://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Tips/tips_on_segmentation.html. Besides, I don't see any issues in your program. Could you debug and tell us the exact location where you get this error.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code, are you sure your entering the number when it ask for the scanf?

Comment: Lakshitha, thanks for giving me the link, it is mostly concentrated upon misuse of dereferencing operators and ampersand operators which I haven't used in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt try but it does not seem contains error.Check your number will be calculated factorial.Do you type negative or too big number?If you enter negative number,recursive function will not exit.

Comment: it's simply displaying 
segmentation error:core(dumped)

Answer (score 0):

I copied-pasted your program in the online https://www.onlinegdb.com/
and run it with no problem. I gave small input numbers like 5 and 12, and it calculated the factorial. So the compilation happened with no issue, and then it moved on to the execution phase.  I also put the -Wall as Command line arguments , and again it compiled and run. The only improvement to your program could be to output a line of instructions, 
"Enter an integer >1 :" 
and also when you read input by user , first check that it is >1 and then call the function, else terminate execution without calling the function.

Comment: thanks Georgios, it ran on the link you gave t me, it didn't run anywhere else sadly